# Send message to LogCat

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, libgdx, logcat

I am looking for a way to sent myself messages for debugging my app on a device. If I understand correctly `LogCat` is used for this. But I am unable to sent/output messages to `LogCat`.

I tried the following without results:

```
System.out.println("Message"); //Outputs to console when in desktop app, nothing on device.
Log.i + Log.d + Log.w //These methods do not exist. And i cannot get `Log` to work in any other way.
Debug.println("Msg1", "Msg2"); //Ends up in a error on device.
```

I simply want to sent myself "debug" messages while on my phone, Like coordinates where has been clicked. I do not necessarily need `LogCat` if it is not needed for this purpose.

Comment: what's the problem with Log.d(String tag, String message) method?

Comment: He's using LibGDX, which doesn't let you access that API directly. I noted which methods he should be using instead in my answer.

Comment: I'm the only one here who gets log on android from system.out.println?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`android.util.Log` is the class that has the methods you want, i.e. Log.i(), Log.w(), and so on.

If they 'don't exist', make sure you're importing the class.

EDIT: Sorry, missed the libgdx tag. In LibGDX, use these methods instead:

```
Gdx.app.log("MyTag", "my informative message");
Gdx.app.error("MyTag", "my error message", exception);
Gdx.app.debug("MyTag", "my debug message");
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually used Gdx.app.log too, but did not look at the info level. You might want to add that too for future reference.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in your core libgdx project, use `Gdx.app.log("tag", "msg");`. This gets passed through to Android's `Log.i()` in the Android build. You can't access Android APIs directly in the core project.